# SSH forwarding domain:port to EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a host `local-dev` that maps to a VM's IP address.

Theres an AWS EC2 instance running a webserver, to which I want to enable ssh forwarding on a certain port i.e. I want it to forward any requests made to `local-dev:85` to the ec2 instance.

`local-dev` is also configured with `dnsmasq` to support subdomains, and these subdomains *must* work and be forwarded too.

Whats the best way of doing this? I've tried a bunch of `ssh -L` type commands, but they all fail for one reason or another. One of the problems is that the ssh happens for the `ec2-user`, and I presume it must happen as root.

Answer (score 0):

well there are two options:

1. do it with iptables on the local-dev instance

   `iptables -A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d ip-of-local-dev/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 85 -j DNAT --to-destination ip-of-ec2-instance:target_port`

or

2. you can do it with SSH tunnel. The port for incomming on the `local-dev` server needs to be above 1024 when you don´t want to do it as root

   `-L 0.0.0.0:1085:ip-of-ec2-instance:target_port`